# Insert_batch from json api

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

How to input several row of data into sql.My code only input the first set of  data

controller page:

```
public function all_report(){
        if($this->input->post('save'))
        {   
            $machine_name = $this->input->post('device_type');
            $jdata = json_decode($this->input->post('my_data'));
            $response=$this->post_model->savedata($jdata, $machine_name);
            if($response==true){
                $message = "Data import Successfully";
                echo "<script>alert('$message');</script>";
            }
            else{
                $message = "Data import Fail";
                echo "<script>alert('$message');</script>";
            }
        }
```

model page :

```
        function savedata($jdata, $machine_name)
        { 
           if($machine_name=="machine1"){
              $adata = array($jdata);
              $this->db->insert_batch('table1',$adata);
              return true;
        }
```

data retrieved but only first set of data insert into sql.From my understanding insert_batch must be in array thats why I array the json data

[image: json]

[image: phpmyadmin]

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Isn't `$jdata` already an array? Why wrapping it into another array as `$adata`?

Comment: i might be confuse because I tried `$this->db->insert('display_da_silo3',$jdata);`  but result is only insert first set of data...change to insert_batch will cause error hence the array as `$adata`

Comment: since it's a JSON object you might need to use `json_decode()`.  Use a `foreach` loop and add one by one or before `insert_batch` check data validity

Comment: @AbdullaNilam thnks for telling me to validate data just discover my own problem..sometimes we did some silly mistakes eh?hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im so sorry I just discover my own problem.Its my json api I make it `parse_data[0]` instead of `parse_data` thats why it only insert first set of data..so in model it should be `$this->db->insert_batch('display_da_silo4',$jdata); return true;` thank you for telling me to validate data ;)